# Chartjs: how can i create a graph with multiple jsons files?

Tags: chart.js

I have 20 jsons files. In every file there are 12 markers:

```
{"mean":0.08614979321142166,
 "min":-3.1884,
 "max":2.1901,
 "peak2peak":5.3785000000000007,
 "std":1.0903240544512534,
 "variance":1.1888065437150195,
 "kurtosis":2.165975182739587,
 "skewness":-0.041289626007299074,
 "rmsOriginalSignal":1.0937041158972693,
 "rmsFiltSignal_01":1.0922792414296567,
 "rmsFiltSignal_02":0.00036638538212209666,
 "rmsFiltSignal_03":0.032341062844535272}
```

I have to create a graph like this with mean:

[mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE4TO.png)

How can I load this external json files, also from a local folder?
 How can I take every mean from every single file and create a graph for mean?

Comment: can you please show us, one of your json file if it is not so big ?

Comment: I add my json file

Comment: Well, what's your problem ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on java and html. One i would like to know how load multiple json files… second I would like to know how to merge the files to create a graph of mean like the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, in your json files, the structure like below.

`var jsonObjectArray = [{"mean":0.08614979321142166,
 "min":-3.1884,
 "max":2.1901,
 "peak2peak":5.3785000000000007,
 "std":1.0903240544512534,
 "variance":1.1888065437150195,
 "kurtosis":2.165975182739587,
 "skewness":-0.041289626007299074,
 "rmsOriginalSignal":1.0937041158972693,
 "rmsFiltSignal_01":1.0922792414296567,
 "rmsFiltSignal_02":0.00036638538212209666,
 "rmsFiltSignal_03":0.032341062844535272}, 
{"mean":0.08614979321142166,
 "min":-3.1884,
 "max":2.1901,
 "peak2peak":5.3785000000000007,
 "std":1.0903240544512534,
 "variance":1.1888065437150195,
 "kurtosis":2.165975182739587,
 "skewness":-0.041289626007299074,
 "rmsOriginalSignal":1.0937041158972693,
 "rmsFiltSignal_01":1.0922792414296567,
 "rmsFiltSignal_02":0.00036638538212209666,
 "rmsFiltSignal_03":0.032341062844535272}, ....]`

you can use loadash.js map function to pisk just mean property from json object array.

```
_.map(jsonObjectArray, "mean");
```

then you will get like `[0.08614979321142166, 0.18614979321142186]`

for example if you are trying to build a web page with all of theese data, you are gonna include 20 different files to html like .js files,  or you are gonna get your json files like below,

```
<script>

var jsonArray = null;
for(i=0; i<19 ; i++){
   $.getJSON('mean' + i + '.json', function(data) {
      jsonArray.push(data);
   });
}
<script/>`
```

I named your 20 json files like mean1.json, mean2.json ... so on.

Comment: thanks for your answer but how can i load my 20 json files from external folder?

Comment: @JamesPoly I updated last answer, wrote one of your possible solutions above.